# Head() does not work after renaming columns

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone let me know how I could fix the following code, please?
I get an attribute error after renaming the columns.
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'**

```
    df4 = df4.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Year', df.columns[1]: 'GDP_cap'}, inplace=True)
    print(df4.head())
```

Comment: For the future, a way to start debugging something like this is to check the type i.e. `print(type(df4))`. This may have pointed you in the right direction. On a different note, you should consider stopping to use `inplace` at all: dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the argument `inplace=true` in a pandas dataframe operation, then nothing is returned. In other words: in the first line of your code example the value `None` gets assigned to name `df4`. Hence the subsequent error.

Solution 1:

```
df4.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Year', df.columns[1]: 'GDP_cap'}, inplace=True)
print(df4.head())
```

Solution 2:

```
df4 = df4.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Year', df.columns[1]: 'GDP_cap'})
print(df4.head())
```

Comment: Worth noting that the pandas devs are phasing option 1 out and recommend that you only use option 2. See https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace

Comment: Thank you so much, Xukrao and Dan.